# Kotlin Retrofit response returning null to data class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm consuming an API service using retrofit but I'm not getting the data back from the response of Retrofit.

I can see the data in the response within the logger but the data class is returning null all the time. I don't see any errors in the Logcat to give me any inclination of what's going on.

**My Retrofit instance and interface**

```
 private val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)    

 val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(logger)
    .connectTimeout(Duration.ZERO)
    .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build()    

 private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    //.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(client)
    .build()
   
 interface OrderInfoApiService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @POST("OrderInfo")
    suspend fun getOrderInfo(@Body orderInfoRequest: OrderingRequest): SolServices
    }

 object OrderInfoApi {
    val retrofitService: OrderInfoApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(OrderInfoApiService::class.java)
    }
```

**Data class, generated using Pojo - SolServices**

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class SolServices {

   @SerializedName("OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct")
   @Expose
   private OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct orderingOrderInfoResponseStruct;

   public OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct getOrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct() {
       return orderingOrderInfoResponseStruct;
   }

   public void setOrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct(OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct 
    orderingOrderInfoResponseStruct) {
    this.orderingOrderInfoResponseStruct = orderingOrderInfoResponseStruct;
  }
```

**Second data class, used by the above**

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct {

    @SerializedName("deliveryAddresses")
    @Expose
    private DeliveryAddresses deliveryAddresses;
    @SerializedName("orderingGroups")
    @Expose
    private OrderingGroups orderingGroups;

    public DeliveryAddresses getDeliveryAddresses() {
        return deliveryAddresses;
    }

    public void setDeliveryAddresses(DeliveryAddresses deliveryAddresses) {
        this.deliveryAddresses = deliveryAddresses;
    }

    public OrderingGroups getOrderingGroups() {
        return orderingGroups;
    }

    public void setOrderingGroups(OrderingGroups orderingGroups) {
        this.orderingGroups = orderingGroups;
    }    
}
```

**My viewModel, where the Api service is called**

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _orderData = MutableLiveData<SolServices>()
    val orderData: LiveData<SolServices> get() = _orderData

    fun getOrderInfo(orderSessionKey: OrderingRequest) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _orderInfoData.value = OrderInfoApi.retrofitService.getOrderInfo(orderInfoRequest = orderSessionKey)
        }
    }
}
```

**JSON response from the Api**

```
    {
  "OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct": {
    "deliveryAddresses": {
      "OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct": [
        {
          "deliveryAddressNo": 5800009,
          "deliveryAddressName": "BASILDON & THURROCK NHS",
          "pointsOfService": {
            "OrderingPointOfServiceStruct": [
              {
                "pointOfServiceNo": 1,
                "pointOfServiceName": "A & E",
                "pointOfServiceDescription": "A & E 12",
                "pointOfServiceOrderingGroupNo": "580-1",
                "orders": {
                  "OrderingOrderStruct": [
                    {
                      "orderType": "inventory",
                      "orderDate": "2023-07-07",
                      "deliveryDate": "2023-07-07",
                      "orderStatus": 0,
                      "articles": {
                        "OrderingArticleStruct": [
                          {
                            "articleNo": 109842,
                            "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS TOP SHEET S",
                            "articleSize": "",
                            "articleTargetQty": 385,
                            "articleMinQty": 0,
                            "articleMaxQty": 0,
                            "articleIntervalQty": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "articleNo": 103046,
                            "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS PILLOWCASE",
                            "articleSize": "",
                            "articleTargetQty": 15,
                            "articleMinQty": 0,
                            "articleMaxQty": 0,
                            "articleIntervalQty": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "articleNo": 106856,
                            "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS BATH TOWEL",
                            "articleSize": "",
                            "articleTargetQty": 24,
                            "articleMinQty": 0,
                            "articleMaxQty": 0,
                            "articleIntervalQty": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "articleNo": 106482,
                            "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS BLANKET THERMAL BLUE",
                            "articleSize": "",
                            "articleTargetQty": 130,
                            "articleMinQty": 0,
                            "articleMaxQty": 0,
                            "articleIntervalQty": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "articleNo": 106812,
                            "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS PATIENT MODESTY GOWN",
                            "articleSize": "",
                            "articleTargetQty": 65,
                            "articleMinQty": 0,
                            "articleMaxQty": 0,
                            "articleIntervalQty": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "articleNo": 106420,
                            "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS PLASTIC BAGS WHITE",
                            "articleSize": "",
                            "articleTargetQty": 75,
                            "articleMinQty": 0,
                            "articleMaxQty": 0,
                            "articleIntervalQty": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "articleNo": 106458,
                            "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS BAGS WATER SOLUBLE",
                            "articleSize": "",
                            "articleTargetQty": 25,
                            "articleMinQty": 0,
                            "articleMaxQty": 0,
                            "articleIntervalQty": 0
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "orderingGroups": {
      "OrderingOrderingGroupStruct": [
        {
          "orderingGroupNo": "580-1",
          "orderingGroupDescription": "58000009 BASILDON OPD 1"
        },
        {
          "orderingGroupNo": "580-2",
          "orderingGroupDescription": "58000009 BASILDON OPD 2"
        },
        {
          "orderingGroupNo": "580-3",
          "orderingGroupDescription": "58000009 BASILDON OPD 3"
        },
        {
          "orderingGroupNo": "580-4",
          "orderingGroupDescription": "ROYALFREE TOWER BLOCK"
        },
        {
          "orderingGroupNo": "580-5",
          "orderingGroupDescription": "5800024 ROYAL FREE OPD 2"
        },
        {
          "orderingGroupNo": "580-6",
          "orderingGroupDescription": "5800024 ROYAL FREE OPD 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or logs in the console?

Comment: No, I see no errors.

Comment: Did you implement the onFailure and/or onResponse from retrofit?

Comment: That is implementing the code different to how I've written it currently isn't it?  I'm not using Call<SolServices> and enqueue.

Comment: ah yes i think it is, i think your code is stuck somewhere. Lets say you change your implementation to the call enqueue, maybe the onFailure will give you some information.

Comment: You don't need to switch to call/enqueue. A failure will throw an Exception when you call a Retrofit suspend function, so it will appear in LogCat with a stack trace.

Comment: By any chance, is the reason you think you're getting null that you are checking `orderData.value` directly instead of observing it? If you check the value before the API has returned its response, the value will still be null. You should never be using a LiveData's `value` except to set the new value and possibly compare it to the previous value before setting. LiveData is for observing. If this isn't what's going on, can you show how you're determining that the LiveData is emitting null?

Comment: @Tenfour04 you know what, you could be completely spot on.  I'm not observing the orderData am I! I did think this earlier but thought i'd still be able to see the value going to orderData.  Would i observe in the Fragment or the ViewModel? Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if  you are checking `orderData.value` directly instead of observing it. If you check the value before the API has returned its response, the value will still be null. You should never be using a LiveData's `value` except to set the new value and possibly compare it to the previous value while deciding on the new value to set. LiveData is for observing.

Observing is typically done in the Fragment or Activity. It is possible to observe it in the ViewModel by using `observeForever()`, but then you must be sure you remove the observer in the ViewModel's `onCleared()` to avoid leaking the ViewModel. I have never actually seen any reason to ever observe one in a ViewModel, though.

Comment: Thank you for this, you've certainly put me in the right direction. Would you happen to know any good resource that can show me how to use Observe in my Fragment?  I haven't used this previously.

Comment: Usually, you put `someViewModel.someLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { /* do something with it, the new value */ }`. I originally learned by reading [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and various samples I've seen elsewhere in the documentation, and browsing the source code.

Comment: Thank you, i'll take that approach now. Again, thanks for the help